# How to upload and download Images in xero?

Tags: java, xero-api

I have integrated xero in my application, I want to sync employee information from my application to xero & xero to my application. I found 2 apis to do the same.

1. GET https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees/fb4ebd68-6568-41eb-96ab-628a0f54b4b8
2. POST https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/Employees/

But I couldn't get/update profile images using those images. Is there any other apis available for this? or How can I achieve the same.

Comment: Please remove the unrelated tags, at least `hibernate` and `spring-boot`.

Answer (score 0):

After discussed with Xero support team, I get confirmed that currently there is no API to export or import profile images in Xero.